# Is it possible to develop an free application that have some packages in it and those packages will have fee?

Tags: ipad, app-store

I want to develop an application for iPad. This will be free application. But in the application, there will be packages which will have cost. The user, who download the free version, could buy these packages from the application, not AppStore. I mean of course Apple takes %30 of the price but I want an application that some part of it is free, some with fee. Is this possible? or should I have to develop two different applications (one free application and one paid application)?

Comment: what about In-app purchase?? Isn't that an option too?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [In App Purchase](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.htm) feature.